# Searching for a way for firebase to connect to provider on my behalf

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

Before i use firebase authentication i have read that i need to connect to the provider first. Let me explain.

If i want a Facebook login to authenticate in firebase first id connect to facebook oauth using facebook apis and then after that network call succeeds then i will use firebase api with the token recieved and log into firebase app. Right ?

I  am searching for a way to not have to do two network calls. Is there a way to let firebase api do the work of connecting to provider on my behalf.  This would save the user a network call.

Comment: Firebase Authentication uses OAuth to allow signing in with Facebook. The OAuth protocol requires that the client connects to both Facebook and Firebase in this scenario. There is nothing you can do to change this.

Comment: The number of network calls will be the same as Frank said. However, Firebase Auth for web takes care of the whole flow for you via signInWithPopup/Redirect. If you are developing a web app or Cordova app, this would be simplified for you.

Comment: Now it makes now sense when you mentioned firebase web. This is the accepted answer